# Bad VNC artefacts / tearing using Ubuntu 12.04 default VNC server and TightVNC / RealVNC client on Windows

Tags: 12.04, vnc, tearing

I am using the latest daily build of Ubuntu 12.04 on an machine with Asus P5G41T-M motherboard using the built-in graphics (GMA X4500). I have not installed any additional software such as compiz, etc.

I have enabled the default VNC server through the "Desktop Sharing" dialog in settings.
When I connect from a Windows 7 machine using RealVNC or TightVNC, the screen doesn't refresh correctly. There are old images left, the new windows do not appear entirely.

I have tried setting disable_xdamage = true in gconf-editor as others recommended for 11.04 and 11.10 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) i recommend you to install (gnome-panel)  with
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel

and then logout, and login with Ubuntu 2d (unity 2d) this will increase performance on VNC connections, because is not using any effects.

Answer (score 1):

Install `x11vnc` and be sure to select the UltraVNC option when starting the application.  It takes care of the problem.